# Joining two tables to compare with a one to many relationship

Tags: ms-access, compare

I have a table of Purchase Orders and Pay Items as they looked initially.
I also have a table of Purchase Orders and Pay Items as they looked on final award.

```
Initially
PO        Pay Item      Desc            Amt
A            1       Desc Line 1        100
A            1       Desc Line 2         50
A            2       Desc Line 1        200

Award
PO        Pay Item      Desc            Amt
A            1       Desc Line 1        100
A            2       Desc Line 1         80
A            2       Desc Line 2        100
```

Is it possible to have a query that produces the comparison

```
                             INITIAL                   AWARD
PO        Pay Item      Desc            Amt           Desc            Amt
A            1       Desc Line 1        100        Desc Line 1        100
A            1       Desc Line 2         50
A            2       Desc Line 1        200        Desc Line 1         80
                                                   Desc Line 2        100
```

For the Initial Phase Pay Item 1 had two lines, but in the Award Phase it only ended up with one line.

So they are line up on PO and Pay Item but I one may have a different (variable) number of lines than the other.

I don't think the formatting in my question is going to come across very well. Basically I have a key of PO and Pay Item but one table has more lines under the Pay Item than the other.

Comment: Your formatting is confusing. Can you specify what fields are in a Purchase order, what fields are in a Pay Item, and what are the INITIAL and AWARD captions representing?

Comment: My advice is to make a key field in both tables which contains po+pay item+desc then you can simply outer join the two tables in a query to get desired output.

Comment: Yes that would work but if the initial Pay item had 30 lines and award Pay Item has 40 lines you end up with 70 lines used. I was hoping to just have 40 lines for that Pay Item as that was the maximum. Regards - Tom